# How to send a one-time payment via PayPal api

Tags: python, paypal

I want to send someone a payment via the API. Basically, I want to enter the person's PayPal email address and dollar amount and send it. No approvals or anything. Here is what I have so far, which creates a payment:

```
headers = {
    "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID": PAYPAL_USERNAME,
    "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD": PAYPAL_PASSWORD,
    "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE": PAYPAL_SIGNATURE,
    "X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID": PAYPAL_APP_ID,
    "X-PAYPAL-SERVICE-VERSION": PAYPAL_SERVICE_VERSION,
    "X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT": "NV",
    "X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT": "JSON",
}

params = OrderedDict()
params['requestEnvelope.errorLanguage'] = 'en_US'
params['actionType'] = 'PAY'
params['currencyCode'] = 'USD'
params['cancelUrl'] = 'https://example.com/'
params['returnUrl'] = 'https://example.com/'
params['receiverList.receiver.email'] = 'david@example.com'
params['receiverList.receiver.amount'] = '1.00'
res = requests.post(
    "https://svcs{}.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/Pay/".format("" if settings.STAGE == "production" else ".sandbox"),
headers=headers, data=params
)
```

This creates the payment object successfully:

```
>>> data
{u'responseEnvelope': {u'ack': u'Success', u'timestamp': u'2014-11-19T23:52:50.500-08:00', u'build': u'13414382', u'correlationId': u'5fe166107b9e3'}, 
  u'paymentExecStatus': u'CREATED', u'payKey': u'AP-76K6303883448644B'}
```

How would I then 'approve' the payment without logging in or anything, is that possible? I tried doing the following but it raised and error that **payment must be authorized by the sender**.

```
params = OrderedDict()
params['requestEnvelope.errorLanguage'] = 'en_US'
params['payKey'] = 'AP-76K6303883448644B'
res = requests.post(
    "https://svcs{}.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/ExecutePayment/".format("" if settings.STAGE == "production" else ".sandbox"),
headers=headers, data=params )
data = res.json()
```

Once I have the `payKey` can I approve/send then payment without going to a url and manually approving it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you specify the `senderEmail` here, it will initiate an immediate ('implicit') payment:

```
params['senderEmail'] = 'sender@example.com'
```

Here is the documentation for more information: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Pay_API_Operation/